# Opening rtf file in Delphi generates error

Tags: delphi

I am loading a RichEdit file using the following code:

```
RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile('xxx.rtf');
```

This works well.  However when I use the TOpenDialog like this:

```
with DlgOpen do if Execute then RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName);
```

I run into a problem.  The file loads alright but leaves the following error message on the desktop:

[image: error message]

I am using Delphi 2010.  The rtf file was generated using Microsoft Word 2007 and I am running Win10.
How can I get rid of the error message?

Comment: Di you have the preview pane open in your file dialog

Comment: Some RTF files cannot be read by the RichEdit. I have encountered this especially when encountering UTF-8 or Unicode files.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you remove the `with do ..` construct and code it explicitly?

Comment: @HughJones No it does not, why would that generate different code?

Comment: @PaulMichael According to the question, this file can be read, it is only when its filename is first selected by open dialog that problems occur. With probability close to 1, the file dialog preview handler is at fault.

Comment: @Rudi I have some advice for asking. Ask when you have got a few hours to spare. That's when there is a buzz around your question. If you ask and then return hours later, we'll all have moved on and you'll be back on your own.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - if there were a variable `FileName` in the calling code, could this not cause problems?  I have seen this type of `with` issue in other contexts.

Comment: @HughJones He wants the `FileName` from the dialog. Even if any of those functions were passed incorrect arguments, a separate process would not be expected to chirp up with an error message.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I see that, but there is very little context in the question, and there has to be more going on than the OP has shown us.  If `FileName` were to resolve to a document already open in MSWord ... ?  (I am not a `with`-hater btw)

Comment: There's little context in the question. Best policy is that we wait for asker to return and help. Little point speculating.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Your hunch is correct.  When I turn off the preview pane the error message disappears.    How can I code to prevent the use of the preview pane?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can. I think that this is a fundamental defect in Office that you can't do much about. My hunch wasn't really much of a hunch. I've seen the same question (or similar) asked a few times here before. Not sure I've got a good way forward for you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am writing a help viewer for a small application.  I will link the name of the help file to the name of the application, avoiding the use of the file open dialog.  Problem solved!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't prevent the previewer to lock the file you want to read, I would work around it by not loading directly that file but a copy of it.

```
uses IOUtils; 
....
....
var TempFile: string;
....
if DlgOpen.Execute then
begin
  TempFile := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(TPath.GetTempPath) + 'Temp.rtf';
  CopyFile(PChar(DlgOpen.FileName), PChar(TempFile), False);
  RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile(TempFile);
  DeleteFile(TempFile);
end;
```

Comment: I could not get your code to work. However running my original code 
   " with DlgOpen do if Execute then RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName);" does not generate any error messages anymore.  Very strange.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is back.  Rather annoying.

Comment: That's not how you get the temp directory and it's not how you com in paths. And don't build the filename twice. Use a variable. More care needed.

Comment: I modified it following your suggestions, except the com in paths. I don't know of better ways to convert a string to the PChar type that that function expects.

Comment: @MarcGuillot  I run your code.  It works!  But then, right now  my original code works without error messages as well.  I cannot figure out a pattern.  Things seem to happen at random.  Sorry.

Comment: Meant to say combine paths. How can you be sure that GetTempPath ends with a separator?

Comment: I didn't though about that, I have always seen it ending with separators, but you are right, it should be checked.

Comment: Answer still wrong. Hence down vote. I'd fix it for you but you seem to reject edits to your posts on principle.

Comment: Fixed.By the way, I don't reject Edits by moderators, I appreciate your hard work. If you are talking about the Post of backspaces over a image, I didn't notice that you had edited my post, it was so fast that I didn't even think about anyone editing it, I just re-read what I had just post (as I always do looking for errors) and I thought I had forgot to use Self. It wasn't until I saw your comment that I considered that you could have removed them.